# JSON object not mapping to Java object with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

This is my JSON  object from server:

```
"driverInfo": {
  "rideTime": null,
  "rideId": 1105,
  "driverProfile": {
    "userId": 9,
    "firstname": "nawaraj",
    "lastname": "shrestha",
    "phone": "9841444444",
    "email": null,
    "location": {
      "lat": 27.7131382,
      "lng": 85.3255354
    },
    "vehicleType": "Taxi",
    "vehicleNo": "4556",
    "rating": 3.3,
    "imageName": "NAbin25",
    "driverId": 4
  },
  "destinationLocation": null,
  "myLocation": {
    "lat": 27.7131382,
    "lng": 85.3255354
  },
  "otpCode": "7857",
  "trackRideUrl": null,
  "customerId": 1
}
```

And this is my java class

```java
public class RideDetails implements Serializable{
@Nullable
private String rideTime;
private Integer rideId;
private DriverProfile driverProfile;
@Nullable
private LatLng destinationLocation;
@Nullable
private LatLng myLocation;
private String otpCode;
private String trackRideUrl;
private Integer customerId;

public Integer getRideId() {
    return rideId;
}

public Integer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public void setRideId(Integer rideId) {
    this.rideId = rideId;
}

public DriverProfile getDriverProfile() {
    return driverProfile;
}

public void setDriverProfile(DriverProfile driverProfile) {
    this.driverProfile = driverProfile;
}

@Nullable
public LatLng getDestinationLocation() {
    return destinationLocation;
}

public void setDestinationLocation(@Nullable LatLng destinationLocation) {
    this.destinationLocation = destinationLocation;
}

@Nullable
public LatLng getMyLocation() {
    return myLocation;
}

public void setMyLocation(@Nullable LatLng myLocation) {
    this.myLocation = myLocation;
}

@Nullable
public String getRideTime() {
    return rideTime;
}

public void setRideTime(@Nullable String rideTime) {
    this.rideTime = rideTime;
}

public String getOtpCode() {
    return otpCode;
}

public void setOtpCode(String otpCode) {
    this.otpCode = otpCode;
}

public String getTrackRideUrl() {
    return trackRideUrl;
}

public void setTrackRideUrl(String trackRideUrl) {
    this.trackRideUrl = trackRideUrl;
}
}
```

To map the object .. I used Gson like this:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
RideDetails rideDetails = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),RideDetails.class);
```

Everything details of JSON object maps to Java class fine except the `LatLng`.
Though `LatLng` has a value in JSON object from server. All three `LatLng`: `location`, `destinationLocation` and `myLocation` have value `{lat:0.0,lng:0.0}` after mapping. What might be the problem?

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate exact POJO class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LatLng` object from the [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) does contain the `lat` and `lng` parameters. This means your object doens't map.

Create your own `Location` object with the correct parameters to ensure the right mapping. Or make sure the json has `latitude` and `longitude` instead of `lat` and `lng` so it can map to the `LatLng` object automatically.

Also, the hierarchy is wrong. `myLocation`, `destinationLocation` and `location` should by mapped under `DriverProfile`.

Comment: can be please elaborate "make sure the gson has latitude and longitude instead of lat and lng" ..is that possible?

Comment: Well, you said your server provides your JSON. I would assume you can ask your API-guy to change the JSON :).

Answer (score 0):

Location should be part of DriverProfile object.

Answer (score 0):

The `LatLng` class has fields `latitude` and `longitude` which are different from the fields `lat` and `lng` your server is sending as part of the JSON.

Comment: Thank you.. THat was exactly the issue